# How does pixels relate to screen size in CSS

Tags: css

If set the width of a div to 450px. What will happen to the div on a smaller screen say a phone or tablet??

Comment: A div can't have a value. I think you mean width? In this case, it will have the same width on different screens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: If you are using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` it depends on the DPI (dots per inch) of the screen.

From the [CSS Spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#visual-angle-unit):

> 1px = 1/96th of 1 inch

and from [Mozilla Docs on the CSS 2.1 spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag):

> If the pixel density of the output device is very different from that of a typical computer display, the user agent should rescale pixel values. It is recommended that the pixel unit refer to the whole number of device pixels that best approximates the reference pixel. It is recommended that the reference pixel be the visual angle of one pixel on a device with a pixel density of 96dpi and a distance from the reader of an arm's length.

A CSS pixel is actually its own unit and doesn't refer to pixels that you see. If your site with the 450px div is just a standard HTML page and you view it on a phone (in portrait) and a desktop monitor (say 1920x1080), you will notice on the phone the div appears to take up more screen space and on the desktop it will take up less screen space.

I think [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u0rfDeaxehc) does a pretty decent job at explaining it.

---

**If you are not using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` 1px closely represents 1px.**

---

You can test this out for yourself by opening these two pages on a phone:

[Viewport device width meta tag set](https://mydi.cc/is.html)

[Viewport device width meta tag NOT set](https://mydi.cc/nis.html)

Answer (score 0):

A pixel is 1/96 of a inch. However, a inch in this context does not necessarily correspond to a physical inch.

According to the [CSS spec](https://www.thoughtco.com/user-style-sheet-3469931), on a physical media like a printed paper, measures have to be anchored to a physical measure such as an inch or a centimeter, and all other measures would be relative to that.

However on a screen, the measures may be anchored to a pixel, and then the actual size of a pixel should take in account the average *distance* users are holding the screen from their eyes. A pixel size should match a 1/96 physical inch for a device used to be held on arm-length distance. But it would be smaller for mobile screen which is held close, and bigger for a TV screen which is used on distance.

In these cases, the CSS measures of inch, cm etc. would be relative too, keeping the proportion of 1px = 1/96 inch.